# Can you build Ionic apps with PhoneGap Build?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

I've spent the last few days reading up on hybrid app development and all the options available out there. I've eventually decided to go with [Ionic](http://www.ionicframework.com). Thing thing is though, that at my current company we work on Windows machines so we can't build for iOS ourselves, also we don't want to go through all the trouble of installing the Android and Windows Phone SDKs just so that we can do builds and run emulators. We'd rather do our testing and development running the app in-browser using `ionic serve`. But then it comes to building the app, I see that PhoneGap has something called [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/). Now the question is, can I take an app that has been developed with Ionic, and compile and build it using PhoneGap build?

Comment: sure, just upload yor www folder to phonegap build, it should work

Comment: Awesome! Thanks man :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your ionic app for all target you want with intel XDK for free.
it build in cloud and provide facilities to deploy, test...

Comment: yep the company I work for uses intel xdk for all of our testing, and production builds

Comment: Unfortunately "Intel® XDK has been discontinued"